# java catching stack overflow, getting msg display and return issues

Tags: java, recursion, exception, stack-overflow

So I'm using this recursive method to calculate the product of two numbers by recursive addition.  I know that big numbers overflow the stack and my intention is to catch the stack overflow exception so the program don't crash.  However, I don't understand why the output message displays several times in the same line and the return 0 is never passed out of the method.  returning 0 is not that important, I'm forced to have a return statement.  But instead of getting back 0, I'm getting back what seems random large numbers.
I would love for it to just display the message once and pass my value back or better yet terminate the method and just return the message.  Any ideas?

here is the method:

```
public static long multiplicationRecursive(long num1, long num2) {

    try {
        if (num2 == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return num1 + multiplicationRecursive(num1, num2 - 1);
        }
    } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
        System.out.println("Recursion failed");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to catch the error only once, at the point where you call the method for the first time (and remove the `try/catch` from the recursive method):

```
long result = 0L;
try {
    result = multiplicationRecursive(num1, num2);
} catch (StackOverflowError e) {
    System.out.println("Recursion failed");
    result = 0L;
}
```

The problem with your approach is that sure, the exception gets caught, but then the method exits normally and goes back to the point where it was called recursively, effectively returning a bogus value.

Answer (score 0):

whats happening is, when your recursive method call gets exception , it goes to catch block and since it has return 0, it comes back to caller with the value 0. and your caller is always will be as below

```
return num1 + multiplicationRecursive(num1, num2 - 1);
```

so `num1+0` will happen internally and it returns the computed value till the exception.
since exception occured your recursive method will stop so it will print computed value as `num1+0`

see below code to have proper recursive handling

```
if (num2 == 0) {
    return 0;
} else {
    try{
     //System.out.println("before oper");

            if(multiplicationRecursive(num1, num2 - 1)==0){
                return 0;
            }

            else{
                return num1 + multiplicationRecursive(num1, num2 - 1); 
            }

}
     catch (StackOverflowError e) {
            System.out.println("Recursion failed");
            return 0l;
        }
    //return 0;
}
```